# "Value cannot be null" when Filtering CollectionViewSource

Tags: c#, wpf

I keep getting this error

```
System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source'
```

I understand why I get this error. Because, when I filter the data here

```
void FilterOrdersBySelectedTag()
{
    if (SelectedTag != null)
    {
        if (SelectedTag.TagName == "All")
        {
            CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.Orders).Filter = null;
        }
        else
        {
            CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.Orders).Filter =
                item => (item as OrderModel).Tags.Contains(SelectedTag.TagId);
        }
    }
}
```

Some `Orders` `tags` are set as `null` (Which they can be) - that's why I get the error. Now, I am stuck - I don't know how to handle this `null` value when dealing specifically with `CollectionViewSource`.

I have tried the following

```
CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.Orders).Filter =
    item => (bool)((item as OrderModel).Tags?.Contains(SelectedTag.TagId));
```

But now I get this error

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Nullable object must have a value.'
```

**Full Code**

```
namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<TagModel> Tags { get; private set; } = new ObservableCollection<TagModel>();
        private TagModel _selectedTag;
        public TagModel SelectedTag
        {
            get { return _selectedTag; }
            set
            {
                _selectedTag = value;
                FilterOrdersBySelectedTag();
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<OrderModel> Orders { get; private set; } = new ObservableCollection<OrderModel>();

        public VM()
        {
            LoadTags();
            LoadOrders();
        }

        void LoadTags()
        {
            Tags.Add(new TagModel
            {
                TagId = 0,
                TagName = "All"
            });
            Tags.Add(new TagModel
            {
                TagId = 1,
                TagName = "Tag 1"
            });
            Tags.Add(new TagModel
            {
                TagId = 2,
                TagName = "Tag 2"
            });
        }

        void LoadOrders()
        {
            Orders.Add(new OrderModel
            {
                OrderId = 5000,
                OrderName = "ORD10000",
                Tags = new int[] { 1 }
            });
            Orders.Add(new OrderModel
            {
                OrderId = 5001,
                OrderName = "ORD10001",
                Tags = new int[] { 1, 2 }
            });
            Orders.Add(new OrderModel
            {
                OrderId = 5002,
                OrderName = "ORD10002"
            });
        }

        void FilterOrdersBySelectedTag()
        {
            if (SelectedTag != null)
            {
                if (SelectedTag.TagName == "All")
                {
                    CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.Orders).Filter = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.Orders).Filter =
                        item => (bool)((item as OrderModel).Tags?.Contains(SelectedTag.TagId));
                }
            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public class OrderModel
    {
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public string OrderName { get; set; }
        public int[] Tags { get; set; }
    }

    public class TagModel
    {
        public int TagId { get; set; }
        public string TagName { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is necessary to set a value for the zero element, that is, pass them through the filter or not.
An example eliminating zero elements.

```
            else
            {
                CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.Orders).Filter =
                    item => (item as OrderModel)?.Tags?.Contains(SelectedTag.TagId)
                        ?? false;
            }
```

> Hi, this just returns me all the data.

It means you have no zero elements.
Expand the body of the lambda, put a breakpoint in it and check why this is happening.

Equivalent lambda code, but in a more Debug-friendly form:

```
    CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.Orders).Filter =
        item =>
        { // Breakpoint at this line.

            OrderModel order = item as OrderModel;
            if (order != null)
            {
                TagModel tag = order.Tag;
                if (tag != null)
                    return tag.Contains(SelectedTag.TagId);
            }
            return false;
        };
```

Comment: Hi, this just returns me all the data.

Comment: Read the addition in my answer.